# How to write data to google sheet in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, google-sheets-api

I'm working on a App which I need to update data from smartphone (User type in) to a Google spreadsheet.
I know I need to create a cloud project, open Sheet API, get the API key,
and add implementation.

```
implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.34.1'
implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-sheets:v4-rev20230227-2.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.42.3'
```

But I can't understand how to do next step like how to communicate with spreadsheet. Guides only have Java, python, etc.
I try to change Java code into Kotlin, and just show "FATAL EXCEPTION". Please help!

I tried so far:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.Matrix
import android.location.Location
import android.location.LocationListener
import android.location.LocationManager
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.*
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.net.toUri


import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.*
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.*
import java.io.*
import java.util.*


 
//private val CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json"
//I see Java code using .json file to auth the permission,I put file in "app\src\main\res", but I'm not sure is crroect or not.

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
 
    private val SCOPES = listOf(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS)
    private val googleSheetID = "MYSHEETID"
    private val googleSheetName = "MYSHEETNAME_TOO"
    private val range = "B1"
    //I have changed that to my sheet ID.
    val credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, listOf(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS))
    //I create OAuth2 and service account too. 
    //GoogleAccountCredential UNRESOLVE REFERENCE error
    
    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)        


        val locationManager = getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
        val locationListener = object : LocationListener {
            override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
                findViewById<TextView>(R.id.longitude).text = location.longitude.toString()
                findViewById<TextView>(R.id.latitude).text = location.latitude.toString()
            }
            override fun onStatusChanged(provider: String?, status: Int, extras: Bundle?) {
            }
            override fun onProviderEnabled(provider: String) {
            }
            override fun onProviderDisabled(provider: String) {
            }
        }
        findViewById<Button>(R.id.load_from_GPS).setOnClickListener {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this,"@string/btn_GPS",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), 1)
                return@setOnClickListener
            }
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0L, 0f, locationListener)
        }

        findViewById<Button>(R.id.reportBt).setOnClickListener {
            val textView0: TextView = findViewById(R.id.longitude)
            val textView1: TextView = findViewById(R.id.latitude)
            val textTemp0 = textView0.text.toString()
            val textTemp1 = textView1.text.toString()
            textTemp = textTemp0+","+textTemp1
            val valueRange = ValueRange().setValues(listOf(listOf(textTemp)))
            
            sheetsService.spreadsheets().values()
                .update(googleSheetID, googleSheetName + "!" + range, valueRange)
                .setValueInputOption("RAW")
                .execute()
        }//sheetsService UNRESOLVE REFERENCE error  
    }   
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.